# set_error_handler code error is 1024 in every case

Tags: php, error-handling, warnings, notice

I am working on the following error handler project.

```
function test($code, $message, $fichier, $ligne){

    switch($code){

        case E_USER_NOTICE :

            print_r('notice');

            break;
        case E_USER_WARNING :

            print_r('warning');

            break;
        case E_USER_ERROR :

            print_r('error');

            break;

    }


    echo '<pre>',print_r($code,true),'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>',print_r($message,true),'</pre>';
}

set_error_handler('test');

trigger_error(E_USER_WARNING);
```

The problem is that for every error i try to trigger i get a `1024` error code and it print 'notice'.

However the message print the good code error (here `512`). But i would like to get the good code and not with the message.

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I'll learn to use the trigger_error method ...

first param = message,

second param = code